# MySQL Workbench has stopped working the first time i want to run it

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

When i was installing MySQL Workbench i got this error :

> updating start menu link failed

but i complete the installation till the end

And after installing the program, i try to launch the `MySQLWorkbenchand` i got this error :

[image]

**View Problems Details:**

> Problem signature:
>
> Problem Event Name:  APPCRASH
>
> Application Name:    MySQLWorkbench.exe
>
> Application Version: 6.3.4.0
>
> Application Timestamp:   55758818
>
> Fault Module Name:   KERNELBASE.dll
>
> Fault Module Version:    6.1.7601.18015
>
> Fault Module Timestamp:  50b8479b
>
> Exception Code:  e0434352
>
> Exception Offset:    0000000000009e5d
>
> OS Version:  6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
>
> Locale ID:   1033
>
> Additional Information 1:    7878
>
> Additional Information 2:    787854380ac502069a277b7321ff9e3f
>
> Additional Information 3:    f71d
>
> Additional Information 4:    f71d629042a87fe3e1c1c515dad1788a
>
> Read our privacy statement online:
>
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409
>
> If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy
>
> statement offline:
>
> C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt

And i try to reconfigure these but no result :

[image]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Can you select "View Problem Details" and update your question to include it?

MySQL Workbench also requires:

- [Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17113)
- [Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2013](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784)

The installer is pretty good about making you install those, but I'd make sure they're installed anyway too :-).

Comment: ok i update it , please check it and tell me what i should do , thankss

Comment: Ah that's a .NET crash, the error should have been reported in the Windows Event Log ("Event Viewer" on your start menu) under the Application Log probably with the Source ".NET Runtime"

Comment: In my case, 64 bit version of Visual C++ Redistributable was bot installed.